# angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: pendingRequestsProvider <- pendingRequests <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I have looked at every example I could find on the web and have not been able to resolve this one. We are using TypeScript with AngularJs. I continue to get the unknown provider error regardless of the changes we have made. Since it is an httpInterceptor I am tying it in to Application.TS and placing the call in _Layout.cshtml. Thank you for your help!

This is my Application.TS file

```
/// <reference path='../Typescript/angularjs/angular.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='../Typescript/angular-growl-v2/angular-growl-v2.d.ts' />
/// <reference path="Controllers/PendingRequests.ts" />

module TrainingTrackerAdmin {
    import ILocationProvider = ng.ILocationProvider;
    import ICompileProvider = ng.ICompileProvider;
    import IGrowlProvider = ng.growl.IGrowlProvider;
    import IHttpProvider = ng.IHttpProvider;
    import IPendingRequests = PendingRequests.IPendingRequests;

    var myApp = angular.module('trainingTrackerAdmin', ['ngAnimate', 
'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.tree', 'angular-growl']);

myApp.controller(
  "AppController",
  function ($scope: any, $http: any, pendingRequests: IPendingRequests) {
    $scope.PendingRequests = pendingRequests; 
  }
);
myApp.config([
  '$locationProvider', '$compileProvider', 'growlProvider', '$httpProvider',
      ($location: ILocationProvider, $compile: ICompileProvider, growl: 
IGrowlProvider, $httpProvider: IHttpProvider, pendingRequests: 
IPendingRequests) => {
            $location.html5Mode(true);
            $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
          //turn off caching for admin
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Cache-Control': 'no-
cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache' }; 
            $compile.debugInfoEnabled(true);
            growl.onlyUniqueMessages(false)
                .globalTimeToLive(5000)
              .globalDisableCountDown(true);

            function interceptHttp($q: any, pendingRequests: 
IPendingRequests) {
              function interceptRequest(config: any) {
                alert('interceptRequest');
                pendingRequests.startRequest();
                return config;
              }

              function interceptRequestError(rejection: any) {
                alert('interceptRequest');
                pendingRequests.startRequest();
                return $q.reject(rejection);
              }

              function interceptResponse(response: any) {
                alert('interceptRequest');
                pendingRequests.endRequest();
                return response;
              }

              function interceptResponseError(response: any) {
                alert('interceptRequest');
                pendingRequests.endRequest();
                return $q.reject(response);
              }

              return {
                request: interceptRequest,
                requestError: interceptRequestError,
                response: interceptResponse,
                responseError: interceptResponseError
              };
            }

            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptHttp);
        }
    ]);
}
```

and this is the class it is referencing:

```
module TrainingTrackerAdmin.PendingRequests {

  export interface IPendingRequests {
    startRequest(): void;
    endRequest(): void;
    any: boolean;
    none: boolean;
  }

export class PendingRequests implements ng.IServiceProvider, IPendingRequests 
{
private requests: number;
constructor() {
  this.requests = 0;
}
public startRequest(): void {
  this.requests++;
  console.log(`pendingRequests : ${this.requests}`);
}
public endRequest(): void {
  this.requests--;
  console.log(`pendingRequests : ${this.requests}`);
}
public get any(): boolean {
  console.log(`${this.requests} !== 0 :${this.requests !== 0} `);
  return this.requests !== 0;
}
public get none(): boolean {
  console.log(`${this.requests} === 0 :${this.requests === 0} `);
  return this.requests === 0;
}
$get(): IPendingRequests {
  return this;
}
}
angular.module('trainingTrackerAdmin').provider('PendingRequests', 
PendingRequests)
.config(['PendingRequestsProvider', function (PendingRequests: 
ng.IServiceProvider) {
}]);
}
```

The html for it is called in _Layout.cshtml like this:`

```
<div class="loadingBackground"  ng-show="pendingRequests.any">
<div class="loadingCell">
  <p class="loadingImage"> </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Loading</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual provider name is `PendingRequests`, but you use `pendingRequests` in controller dependencies. Injector is case sensetive, so you should use `pendingRequests` as provider name (according to [styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y125)). Also, your controller dependencies are [not minification-safe](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y100)

----------Update---------

There is another issue:

```
myApp.config([
  '$locationProvider', '$compileProvider', 'growlProvider', '$httpProvider',
      ($location: ILocationProvider, $compile: ICompileProvider, growl: 
IGrowlProvider, $httpProvider: IHttpProvider, pendingRequests: 
IPendingRequests) => {
............
```

You can not inject services into `.config`, only providers. So it must be

```
myApp.config([
  '$locationProvider', '$compileProvider', 'growlProvider', '$httpProvider', 'pendingRequestsProvider', 
      ($location: ILocationProvider, $compile: ICompileProvider, growl: 
IGrowlProvider, $httpProvider: IHttpProvider, pendingRequestsProvider: 
IPendingRequests) => {
............
```

Comment: I tried changing the case but it did not solve this. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @flurp by the way, it seems you don't need to inject pendingRequestsProvider into the `.config` at all - you do not use it.

Comment: I added PendingRequestsProvider as I was not able to get it to recognize PendingRequests. I have 4 references to it in the lower part of Application.ts. I tried replacing pendingRequests with pendingRequestsProvider and replaced the references below that with pendingRequerstsProvider but am still getting this error- angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: pendingRequestsProvider <- pendingRequests <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile

Comment: I meant I am getting this error- Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: PendingRequestsProviderProvider <- PendingRequestsProvider <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile

Comment: @flurp lest update question post with actual correct code